# Synology - Cron job

Tags: linux, cron, synology

I'm trying to make cron jobs or task schduler working, but I can not figure out why my script is not taken in consideration.

I'm trying to simply archive a folder with:

```
tar -cvf /volume1/NetBackup/Backups/Monday.tgz /volume1/NetBackup/Backups/ns3268116.ovh.net/
```

Each time the script starts working but cannot achieve the work. Either with task scheduler or crontab, a file Monday.tgz is created in folder /volume1/NetBackup/Backups/, but this file is only 1024 bytes.

Comment: You should specify what model of Synology you are using and what DSM version.

Comment: ssh in and extecute `cat /etc.defaults/VERSION` should give us some useful details.

Answer (score 7):

Synology Cron is really fussy.

Here are my own personal notes for Synology DS413j, DSM 5.2:

1. Hand edit /etc/crontab as root, `crontab -e` isn't available
2. Ensure you use tabs not spaces to separate the columns
3. Your crontab changes may not survive a reboot if there are syntax problems
4. The `who` column in crontab may not be reliable. Use `root` in the who column and `/bin/su -c '<command>' <username>` to run as another other user
5. remember that it uses `ash` not `bash` so check for bashisms, e.g use `>> /path/to/logfile 2>&1' not`&>> /path/to/logfile`
6. It doesn't support 'MAILTO='
7. you need to restart crond `synoservicectl --reload crond` for the new crontab to take effect

Answer (score 2):

You may try adding some diagnostics to it. For instance:

1. Add MAILTO into the crontab file (on top of crontab -e) to receive cron errors by email:

   MAILTO=username@domain.com
2. Redirect output of your tar command to the file:

   your command > ~/log.txt 2>&1
3. Check cron log and look for anomalies. For instance (it may depend on your configuration):

   /var/log/cron.log

You may also try searching through /var/log/messages at the time of your cron job.

Is volume1 a resource on remote host? If yes, it is worth checking this part of the system.

Comment: `MAILTO` and `crontab -e` don't work in my Synology box at least.

Answer (score 0):

I agree about the really nagging nature of Crontab on Synology Linux OSs.

I would certainly suggest to create de desired job as a `.sh` shell script and call it via CRON task inserted by using the GUI, as suggested [here](http://www.iholken.com/index.php/2016/03/28/configure-owncloud-to-use-system-cron-in-synology-nas-dsm-6-rc/).
As for today (March 2017) is the best method I have found, since working with crontab via CLI is nearly a pain.